# Is there a keyboard shortcut for mouse triple-click (using Windows 10)?

Tags: windows, keyboard, click, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

When writing code, I often have to triple-click the mouse to highlight a line or paragraph. Is there a way to do this via the keyboard? I am using Windows10. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a general shortcut, that I'm aware of. Actually even the triple-click is not a Windows shortcut (unless they added it in Windows 10, I'm not using it right now), it has to be implemented by each specific application -or by the control they're using-.

Some editors have shortcuts specific for them, to select a line or a paragraph.

In general of course if you want to select a line you can type *home* followed by *shift*+*end* , to select a paragraph you'll have to go to its first line if you aren't already, then *home* followed by *shift* + as many *arrow downs* as there are lines (sometimes it's more convenient to use the mouse to select the end of the paragraph: when you are at its start keep *shift* pressed and click on a point just after the end of the paragraph).